# Error: Back reference type (java.util.Set) not compatible with managed type

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Goodmorning, i have a problem with a study project. If you consider the ER schema in the image, you can see one relation many-to-many with an associated table. The table Personaggi is composed:

- ID_PERSONAGGIO (Auto Generated)
- Name

[image]

My scope is that of insert with Postman, only one Personaggio without to insert an Albo. Therefore i try to call the API with Postman and pass this Json

> {"nome": "Wolverine"}

but i recive this response:

> "status": 415,
> "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
> "message": "Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported"

On the console i have this

> 2020-10-21 09:06:04.647 WARN 33208 --- [nio-5051-exec-2] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class it.xxxxx.xxxxx.entities.Personaggio]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.Set) not compatible with managed type (it.xxxx.xxxx.entities.Albo)

**Controller**

````
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/personaggio")
public class PersonaggioController {
 
    @Autowired
    PersonaggioService personaggioService;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/inserisci", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> insertNewCollezione(@Valid @RequestBody Personaggio personaggio, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        
        ObjectNode responseNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
        
        responseNode.put("code", HttpStatus.OK.toString());
        responseNode.put("message", "Inserimento Personaggio " + personaggio.getNome() + " Eseguita Con Successo");
 
        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseNode, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}```

    @Entity
@Table(name="personaggi")
@Data
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
property  = "idPersonaggio", 
scope     = Integer.class)
public class Personaggio implements Serializable  {
 
    public Personaggio(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;       
    }
    
    public Personaggio() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4390691806313380055L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_personaggio")
    private Integer idPersonaggio;
    
    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String nome;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="personaggio")
    // @JsonManagedReference(value = "listPersonaggiAlbo")
    private Set<AssAlboPersonaggi> listPersonaggi = new HashSet<>();
    
}

/******************** AssAlboPersonaggi *************/
 
@Entity
@Table(name="ass_albo_personaggi")
@Data
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
property  = "id", 
scope     = AssAlboPersonaggiKey.class)
public class AssAlboPersonaggi {
 
    @EmbeddedId
    AssAlboPersonaggiKey id = new AssAlboPersonaggiKey();
    
    @ManyToOne
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_albo", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    // @JsonBackReference(value = "listAlboPersonaggio")
    Albo albo;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_personaggio", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    // @JsonBackReference(value = "listPersonaggioAlbo")
    Personaggio personaggio;
    
    @Column(name = "flg_protagonista")
    private boolean flgProtagonista;
}
 
/******************** Albo  *************/
 
@Entity
@Table(name="albi")
@Data
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
property  = "idAlbo", 
scope     = Integer.class)
public class Albo implements Serializable{
 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6046242309533678207L;
    
    public Albo(double prezzoDiAcquisto, int numeroAlbo, String annoDiPubblicazione, String meseDiPubblicazione, String titoloAlbo) {
        this.prezzoDiAcquisto = prezzoDiAcquisto;
        this.numeroAlbo = numeroAlbo;
        this.annoDiPubblicazione = annoDiPubblicazione;
        this.meseDiPubblicazione = meseDiPubblicazione;
        this.titoloAlbo = titoloAlbo;
    }
    
    public Albo() { }
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_albo")
    private Integer idAlbo;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @JoinColumn(name = "collezione", referencedColumnName = "id_collezione")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Collezione collezione;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "albo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    // @JsonManagedReference(value = "listAlboPersonaggio")
    private Set<AssAlboPersonaggi> listPersonaggi = new HashSet<>();
    
    @Column(name="prezzo_acquisto")
    private Double prezzoDiAcquisto;
    
    @Column(name="numero")
    private Integer numeroAlbo;
    
    @Column(name="anno_pubb")
    private String annoDiPubblicazione;
    
    @Column(name="mese_pubb")
    private String meseDiPubblicazione;
    
    @Column(name="titolo_albo")
    private String titoloAlbo;
````

Comment: try removing 'consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE' from the @RequestMapping annotation

Comment: nothing, not work